# Matplotlib: Print on top of annotationBbox with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot on top of annotationbBox but clearly when I plot marker with ax.plot(...), it goes under the picture. Is there a way to plot on top of that box or should I do something differently?

```
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(94, 27),dpi=56)
for pos, img , color, y_label in zip(grid_jv, X, y, y_labels):
    pos[0] = pos[0]*(size-1)*94
    pos[1] = pos[1]*(size-1)*27
    ab = offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(offsetbox.OffsetImage(img),pos, xycoords="data", frameon=False, box_alignment=(0,0))
    ax2.add_artist(ab)
    ax2.scatter(pos[0]+45, pos[1]-20, color=colors[color], marker=y_label, s=320)
    plt.xlim(0,(size)*94); plt.ylim(0,(size)*27)
```

Here is part of my code to implement how i'm using annotationBbox and marker plotting.

Comment: You are probably looking for `zorder` arg: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html

Comment: Thank you very much, zorder made the trick! By the way what is the logic of number in zorder?

Comment: Think of it as a layers. The higher a number the closer object to "top".